# HTML tag in salesforce Email Templates

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to edit an email template that has (HTML with letterhead) type, and I want to add a button withing the template, but it won't recognize any HTML tags, it takes them as a plain text, does it really accept HTML tags or not? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not support HTML Tags, the HTML with letterhead types are all wyswig editors so any HTML entered directly will be stripped.

If you want to send a custom template using pure HTML you need to use the HTML type or Visualforce type

See the documentation here https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_emailtemplates.htm&type=0